# Solr : Boost Results from a specific collection

Tags: solr, lucene

We have solr index which has multiple collections i.e. collection_data_sales and collection_data_marketing. So when the user performs a search query, both the collections are queried upon using collection alias. Both collections have same solr schema.

Is there a way to boost the result from a specific collection ? 
i.e. Suppose user specifies collection sales data, then search should happen on both collection_data_sales and collection_data_marketing but boost should be given for documents from collection_data_sales.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to differentiate both collections using data from it it will be enough. Lets imagine that in schema you have field type so for collection_data_marketing you have type:marketing and for collection_data_sales you have type:sales.

The only thing now you have to do is to use boost function like for example this:

```
bf=sum(product(query($q1),10), product(query($q2,3)))&q1=type:sales&q2=type:marketing
```

In this example sales will have weight 10 and marketing will have weight 3